# How can I specify different ranges for different variables in vpasolve command in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am solving a set of equations in MATLAB using vpasolve and I would like to give it search ranges for the variables. I know how to do it for one variable but I when I try to give three ranges for three variables, I do not know how it is done. Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the allowed variable range using a `n x 2` matrix as the last argument, i.e. for [`initial_guess`](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpasolve.html#input_argument_d0e153836):

> If init_guess is a matrix with two columns, then the two entries of
>   the rows specify the bounds of a search range for the corresponding
>   variables. To specify a starting point in a matrix of search ranges,
>   specify both columns as the starting point value.

So, `initial_guess` for 3 (`=n`) input variables would be:

```
initial_guess = [x1_start x1_end;
                 x2_start x2_end;
                 x3_start x3_end;]
```